# canon mx310 printer, color ink is empty, why can't I still print with the black ink?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I want to print a document, I set it to grayscale (i.e no color just blank ink) and for some reason I can't print b/c my color ink cartidge is empty.

The blank ink cartridge is fine, why can't I print then?

The error on the printer says:

```
Check INK 

Uo51 COL
```

Comment: When you say that you set it grayscale, what do you mean? Is the document grayscale (ie no color in the document) or did you specifically [set the printer to print in black-and-white](http://imgsrv.worldstart.com/mso-images/print-in-grayscale.gif) in the printer preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Canon wants you to buy colored ink.

This is the usual behavior for color inkjets.

Comment: Not with all models. I have no problems printing without color with older Canons. But, yes, in newer models ...

Answer (score 0):

Because:

1. Black is printed using black but also using a little of other colors at the same time
2. The print head needs to be always be filled with ink, if you don't want to break it and make a damage that's is more expensive to fix it than buying a new printer